# How do I disable scrolling twice on mobile website?

Tags: mobile, scroll

this website: http://mr-chemie.dev-pixalla.de has a scrolling issue on mobile phones and tablets. When scrolling in one direction, everything is working perfectly fine, but as soon as you change the scrolling direction you got to scroll twice. I noticed that when scrolling up after scrolling down, the vertical scroll bar on the right expands out to full height for a moment. When scrolling up the second time everything works fine.

I'm using Elementor page builder for Wordpress and got some knowledge with CSS. The problem did not occur on any other website I created. I just do not know any kind of property to solve my issue, neither did I encounter similar questions when searching for it on the internet.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was caused by shape bottom divider turned on (Elementor, waves divider). The top one works fine. But when bottom is enabled - then the strange behaviour on mobile happens.